# ¿Como definir correctamente?

Tags: definiciones, nombres-propios

Intento unir en un solo nombre los nombres de los siguientes departamentos:

1. Departamento de diseño de aeronaves.
2. Departamento de construcciones aeronáuticas.

Ambas relacionan el objeto de estudio que son las aeronaves, por lo tanto, mis propuestas son las siguientes:

1. Departamento de diseño y construcciones aeronáuticas.
2. Departamento de diseño y construcción de aviones.

¿Cuales es adecuado utilizar y porque?

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara. Estás buscando un término que recoja a la vez "diseño y construcciones"? preguntas si es mejor "diseño y construcciones" que "diseño y construcción" en un determinado contexto? La elección de un nombre determinado no deja de ser una cosa un poco subjetiva...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependería enteramente si para ti aeronaves y aeronáuticas se usan para definir el mismo tipo de objetos, es decir aviones.

Si la respuesta es afirmativa, yo me inclinaría por reducirlo a:

**Departamento de diseño y construcción de aeronaves**

Esto da la noción de que estás hablando de dos fases diferentes de un mismo objeto.

Primero el diseño, después la construcción. Pero hablas simultáneamente de diseño de aeronaves y de construcción de aeronaves.

Si no fuera el caso, y aeronaves tuviera un significado distinto al término aeronáuticas, entonces estarías forzado a separar ambos campos dando significado particular a cada uno y uniéndolos con la conjunción.

Algo como *Departamento de diseño de aeronaves y construcciones aeronáuticas*

Personalmente desde mi perspectiva, la primera opción es mucho mejor, porque en realidad si quieres unir dos departamentos en uno se infiere que tienen algo en común, por lo que diseño y construcción son la diferencia, no lo otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias Meer Meer, estoy de acuerdo con tu explicación, y como escribes, me refiero a dos fases diferentes.